# What is the Document upload limit in a Tririga Environment ? And How can I check?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud

How many sizes of documents I can upload in each Tririga environment?
How can I check?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the current Document limit by going into Admin Console>System Info > Tririga Web Files > Look for the

“MAXIMUM_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_MEGABYTES” entry.

[image: Document upload limit]

If no value is set the system will automatically restrict the max upload to the default value of 20 megabytes.

The limit is there to restrict unnecessary increases in the size of the database.